# How to view a presentation generated by Microsoft Producer for PowerPoint 2002

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

We've been provided a link to a HTML presentation generated by Microsoft Producer for PowerPoint 2002.

This link does not work neither with IE 11, Chrome 31, Firefox 26 nor Safari 7. I've even installed Netscape Navigator 9 for test reasons.

Any ideas to view this presentation without installing Win 95 and IE 5?

Requirements shown by the presentation: Internet Explorer 5.0 or higher, Netscape Navigator 7.0 or higher or Internet Explorer 5.2.2 or higher for Mac.

Unfortunately I cannot provide a test link since this presentation is behind a login.

Comment: Do you have the ability to actually download the file and open it in PowerPoint?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But I'm going to ask them after I've spent 2 hours to find a solution. I've downloaded IETester which does show me the first page but there is an JavaScript error. I do not wanna know what kind of code this M$ tool generated, but it did hurt looking at the JavaScript code... thank you anyway.

Comment: You can safely ignore the Javascript error and click Play then click Loading and you will be able to view the presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to run successfully but it might be because of this particular presentation.

However, here are two ways which might work for you if you've got the same issue:

- Use the compatibility mode in Internet Explorer
- Download and install IETester which allows you to run IE6 in newer versions of Windows

Comment: I can confirm that using IETester's IE 6 tab works to view these types of Web presentations.